# JSON object flattening to CSV one row

Tags: java, json, csv

Has anyone ever been involved with exporting JSON like this one in my sample made only for the purposes of this conversation:

https://gist.github.com/slavisah/97b57a5826dc0b49ee22895035eb244a

It represents a list of material objects (wood, metal etc.) Requirement is that every material has to be written in one line of CSV file with all of it's behaviors and properties, and their sub-lists in relation to them in the same row. Every list is N sized.

My question is  how to structure that CSV file for easiest export/import in my application? Maybe someone is familiar with Java library which is capable of doing things like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good libraries for working with csv files using java...

http://www.beanio.org/

http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out. I suppose one of them will suite my needs.

Comment: beanio is really adequate for my need and intuitive as well. thanks, @httPants

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use Apache poi  the Java API for Microsoft Documents : https://poi.apache.org/